# What happened to the Journal of Artificial Intelligence?

Tags: journals

I'm writing a survey paper in my own research area, and came across [this publication](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/215471630_The_Development_of_a_Particle_Swarm_Based_Optimization_Strategy_for_Pairwise_Testing). It was published in the "Journal of Artificial Intelligence", and has a fair number of citations. The [doi link](https://dx.doi.org/10.3923/jai.2011.156.165) for it is a site called "scialert.net", which is certainly not the journal's page.

However, when searching for this journal, I am unable to find any information about it. Does anyone have information about what happened to the journal?

Comment: I see that the web site hosts many journals: https://scialert.net/journals.php

Answer (score 3):

Googling...

https://www.ansinet.com/guideline.php?issn=1994-5450

https://scialert.net/jhome.php?issn=1994-5450

Some random recent article:

https://scialert.net/fulltextmobile/?doi=jai.2022.1.8&org=11

The article you were looking for: https://scialert.net/fulltextmobile/?doi=jai.2011.156.165&org=11

Looks like it's still in business.